# Response body showing in network but not console

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, fetch-api

When sending a request to a link, and logging the response in the console (`console.log(res)` and `console.log(res.body)`) shows a ReadableStream but nothing is inside of it.

The `bodyUsed` value is also set to `false` and I do not understand why.

My backend is Express:

```
app.post('/newemail', async (req, res) => {
  const email_client = new Emails();
  let inbox = await email_client.create();
  res.set({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
  res.json(inbox)
})
```

And I'm fetching it with:

```
fetch('url', {'method': 'post'}).then(e => console.log(e.body))
```

When I copy the res.body object with a right click, it copies as `{}` showing that there's nothing in it. However, in the Network tab, it shows the proper response.[image: Network response]

Do I need to add other headers to the request or change the way I'm sending the info in the body? Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the documentation of [`fetch()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch). It returns a `Response` object after the Promise is resolved. This Response object is "raw" and contains the data stream of the response, which is the one you are accessing via `Response.body`.

In order to make use of the stream, you can use some of the existing methods such as `blob` / `text` / `json`, which can convert the stream into a more readable format.

In this case, since it is a JSON object, you can use [`Response.json()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) which will wait until the stream ends and parse it into JSON format.

A sample code for your case would be as follow:

```js
fetch('url', { method: 'post' })
  .then((e) => e.json())
  .then((json) => console.log(json));
```

Notice that `.json()` method also returns a Promise! This is why you need to chain your `.then()` in the Promise.